# Why udev doesn't create a symlink to device?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, udev

I have a device connected via USB:
`Bus 001 Device 009: ID 18d1:4ee4 Google Inc. Nexus 4 (debug + tether)`
I've tried to add both:
`ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4ee4", SYMLINK+="pinpad"`
and
`SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4ee4", SYMLINK+="pinpad"` to the `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-payment-devices.rules` for this one.
After creating a rule, I execute `udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger` However, `pinpad` symlink doesn't appear in `/dev`. It also doesn't display in `/dev` in any other kind.
What can be wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to combine the action add and the subsystem ibn teh same line; moreover if you are using a USB the SUBSYSTEM parameter should be USB; have you tried with this line?:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4ee4", SYMLINK+="pinpad"
```

Comment: is `udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger` enough for udev to create a symlink or do I have to reboot PC every time?

Comment: You can do by that way or restarting udev by `service udev restart`